# TFS 2010 restore of backup to DB server.. client receives HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: iis, team-foundation-server

I recently restored the DB portion of my TFS 2010 deployment, currently when clients open old work items they get the error:

error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Apparently this is a caching issue and I have tried the following. Browsing to https://hostname/workitemtracking/v3.0/clientservice.asmx and clicking on StampWorkItemCache followed by Invoke.

This is turn generates the error:

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemLinkChange.SourceID' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemLinkChange.TargetID' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemLinkChange.LinkType' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemLinkChange.IsActive' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemLinkChange.ChangedDate' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemLinkChange.RowVersion' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have fixed this but you need to complete two steps:

- Change the Server Id of the restored collection
- Rebuild the data within the Warehouse

To change the server id log onto the server where the applictaion tier is installed, in a command window browse to %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\ and run the following command:

TfsConfig changeServerId /sqlInstance:[sqlInstance] /databaseName:[databaseName] /projectCollectionsOnly

I've added projectCollectionsOnly switch as I am asuming you have restored a TFS collection database.

To rebuild the warehouse run the following command (this will need to be done otherwise you will end up with duplicate workitems within TFS_Warehouse:

TfsConfig rebuildWarehouse /all

Hope that helps.

Samad

Comment: I still get the same error output as the original questioner, even after restamping the TFS configuration and collection databases. I've recently done a move of the data tier, and while work items seem to be working im concerned about the error message.